# HTML Form generates file download but where did the file come from?

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, google-chrome

I've been using the developer tools in Chrome to see what happens at various points when on a website.  This has helped me automate some tasks that I do from time to time.  I am trying to automate downloading a file with python currently.

https://newjersey.mylicense.com/Verification_4_6/Verification_Bulk_4_6/Search.aspx?facility=Y

Using this website if you fill out the form you will be presented with pages of information, or you can opt to download a csv containing all of the information.  I've been trying to track the source of the data down so that I can use python to download the file periodically using preset filters.  I cannot seem to determine where the file is coming from, I am assuming it is being generated on the fly.

I have copied the request as CURL and converted it to python in the past to do similar tasks.  I can't find the correct request for this file though.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: the file comes from the server

Comment: I understand that, is it possible to grab the file just using requests in Python though?

Comment: yes, send the same request as the browser sends

Comment: Thats why I'm asking for help.  I've tried using the requests that are reported using developer tools in chrome but haven't been able to track down the actual request that processes the file.

Comment: developer tools should show you the requested URL and the request headers and request body (if the request method is not GET) - which part are you having trouble seeing in the developer tools?

Comment: Specifically once I get to the download page and click download it doesn't seem to produce any requests in the dev tools.  Prior to clicking the download link it produces a request and shows the raw HTML with the fist page of results.  I am trying to grab all of the results, preferably in the csv that downloads after you click the download button.  It does look like the request method is a GET though.

Answer (score 0):

As I dug into this issue I was able to get the request being sent for one of the downloads.

```
POST /Verification_4_6/Verification_BULK_4_6/PrefDetails.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: newjersey.mylicense.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://newjersey.mylicense.com/Verification_4_6/Verification_BULK_4_6/PrefDetails.aspx
Cookie: *
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 336

__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJNzM2NTgwNzkyZGSsFPyLciI3gDnR3y%2FxYwHNweKGIEFnJ%2FzBJHPpuNJ1WQ%3D%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=77410E8E&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAASoctjMBW5Qw%2Fn%2BtZORNP%2BrWiH8QdCSloyjmvbgUsikPmZ0ykqcWIOKRv0u40f%2F2wmhB7rIFeftzRbk4tZlnAa2oCHi8XWNfIVtv%2FuYtH%2Bw7cUEy6q8uVxE%2B0k5O1xozJo%3D&sch_button=Download&filetype=delimitedtext
```

Using something like burp suite or wireshark will allow you to catch traffic and analyze the requests being made to/from the web server.

wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/wireshark-filter.html
burp suite: https://portswigger.net/burp